# Hlookup to fill a 151x499 sheet with two variables for range

Tags: vba, excel

I want this `Hlookup` to fill a 151x499 sheet. My issue is coming with having both the x and y variables counting up with each loop. I want x to be 2-152 for all 499 y values.

This is what I have written so far:

```
Sub HlooksforRun()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
For x = 2 To 152
For y = 2 To 500

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("info for run").Select

Cells(x, y) = Application.WorksheetFunction.HLookup(Range("B1"), _
  Worksheets("Ranks (Standard Form)").Range("A1:SH152"), x, False)

Next x
Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: Your issue appears to be related to referencing the inactive sheet in your HLoookup function

Worksheets("Ranks (Standard Form)").Range("A1:SH152")

Comment: The formula itself is not referencing y, isn't this just going to put the same formula across all 498 columns? it will increment across rows but not columns.

Comment: Pretty much, but its unclear what exactly you want this to do.... I was just trying to address the error and let you fix your formula errors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop through the rows. Excel lets you enter formula in all the cells in the column in one go.

See this example which I quickly wrote. (**Untested**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim y As Long
    Dim wsInfo As Worksheet, wsRank As Worksheet
    Dim col As String, sFormula As String

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set wsInfo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("info for run")
    Set wsRank = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ranks (Standard Form)")

    '~~> Loop only through columns
    For y = 2 To 500
        '~~> Get column Name
        col = ReturnName(y)
        '~~> Store the formula in a string. Also notice the use of "$"
        '~~> If you do not want to keep the range constant then remove the "$"
        '~~> Ex: =HLOOKUP(B1,'Ranks (Standard Form)'!$A$1:$AH$283,2,FALSE)
        sFormula = "=HLOOKUP(B1,'" & wsRank.Name & "'!$A$1:$AH$283,ROW(),FALSE)"
        '~~> Insert formula in the entire column in ONE GO
        wsInfo.Range(col & "2:" & col & "152").Formula = sFormula
    Next y

LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    MsgBox "Done"
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub

'~~> Function to get Column Name from Column Number
Function ReturnName(ByVal num As Integer) As String
    ReturnName = Split(Cells(, num).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Sub HlooksforRun()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim rankSheet As Worksheet
Dim infoSheet As Worksheet
Dim myRange As Range

Set infoSheet = Sheets("info for run")
Set rankSheet = Sheets("Ranks (Standard Form)")
Set myRange = rankSheet.Range("B2:SH152")

For x = 2 To 152
    For y = 2 To 500
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("info for run").Activate
        infoSheet.Cells(x, y).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.HLookup(infoSheet.Range("B2"), myRange, x, False)
    Next y
Next x

End Sub
```

Edit: Perhaps this was more along the lines of what you were looking for (This will put the HLookup formula into every cell specified in the loop):

```
Sub HlooksforRun()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim rankSheet As Worksheet
Dim infoSheet As Worksheet
Dim myRange As Range

Set infoSheet = Sheets("info for run")
Set rankSheet = Sheets("Ranks (Standard Form)")
Set myRange = rankSheet.Range("B2:SH152")

For x = 2 To 152
    For y = 2 To 500
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("info for run").Activate
        infoSheet.Cells(x, y).Formula = "=HLOOKUP(B1, 'Ranks (Standard Form)'!A1:AH283," & x & " , FALSE)"
    Next y
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: So that I can use "ActiveCell.Value". For whatever reason trying to directly specify the cells Value seemed to throw me an error.

Comment: I encountered that years ago so I started using infoSheet.Cells(x, y).Formula instead of .Value and it fixed it, I don't know why but it did, now I always use .Formula

Comment: .Formula would actually put the formula into the Cell - whereas Value evaluates it and puts the result. I was just going off what little information was provided.

Comment: .Formula will put in there whatever you tell it to, this part `Application.WorksheetFunction.HLookup(infoSheet.Range("B2"), myRange, x, False)` returns a value so that is what will be put in. For example `Range("A1").Formula = 1+2` will put `3` in range A1 but `Range("A1").Formula = "=1+2"` will put the formula `=1+2` in there (This is why I like .Formula :))